# org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failing batch since transaction was aborted

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.3.6, and my use case is to read message from a topic, process and send the response to a new response topic. In case of any failure or exception, I am catching the exception and sending default response to the response topic. My issue is when I am getting any exception and sending the default response to response topic, I am getting following exception:

> org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failing batch since transaction was aborted
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failing batch since transaction was aborted

Kafka Handler:

```
 catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred in transformed topic handler while processing eventMessage for SIM24ActivationEvent in Sim24ActivationEventHandler, exception = ", e);
       
        operationHelper.publishGenericErrorResponseEvent(topic, message);
    }

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void publishGenericErrorResponseEvent(String topic, String message) {
    try {
        if (Objects.nonNull(message)){
            ProducerRecord<String, String> recordMessage = new ProducerRecord(topic, message);
            kafkaService.sendMessage(recordMessage);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new BusinessException("Something went wrong while publishing response ....");
    }
}


  
   public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sendMessage(final ProducerRecord message) {

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = this.kafkaTemplate.send(message);
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
        public void onSuccess(final SendResult<String, String> messagex) {
            KafkaServiceImpl.LOGGER.info("sent message with offset = {} and message = {}", messagex.getRecordMetadata().offset(), messagex);
        }

        public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {
            KafkaServiceImpl.LOGGER.error("unable to send message= " + message, throwable);
            throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
        }
    });
    return future;
}
```

The underlaying exception is:

```
exception = java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
```

My question is even though I am catching the exception and sending generic response to Kafka then why Kafka producer is throwing the exception and not able to publish the message?

Comment: You need to show more code, configuration, and the full stack trace of the exception, with logs or, preferably, an {MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).